# Printing the Current Value of a loop to a widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to print the current value of a for loop to a QT Widget and I am not sure which widget is the right way to go and how to get the current value passed to the widget.

In detail: 
I have a Signal from a pushButton which will do a set of calculations for variable t. And for every iteration N, I would like to print the iteration number N and variable t value to the Widget (textEdit, LineEdit or what ever is most appropriate). Sort of like what qDebug() does. For Example:

```
double t = 0.0;
for (int N=1; N<50; N++)
{
 t = t + 2;
  ui->textEdit->text(QString::number(t));     
}
```

And I would like my widget to have
N                  t
itertionNumber currentValue_of_t

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use the [`QTextEdit::append`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append) method.

```
double t = 0.0;

for (int N = 1; N < 50; N++)
{
    t += 2.0;
    QString line = QString("\tN=%1\tt=%2").arg(N).arg(t);
    te.append(line);
}
```

This logs:

```
    N=1     t=2
    N=2     t=4
    N=3     t=6
    N=4     t=8
    N=5     t=10
    ...
    N=45    t=90
    N=46    t=92
    N=47    t=94
    N=48    t=96
    N=49    t=98
```

Regarding the widget to use text-edits are the most appropriate as they allow for new-lines (line-edits don't). The *Application Output* panel of QtCreator most likely uses a text-edit.

[<sup>**Demo on Github**</sup>](https://github.com/TrebledJ/Qt-Examples/tree/master/%5Bwidgets%5D--logging)

Comment: In the question does not say that you want to see the text in every second, only to be shown so it is not necessary to use QThread::sleep(), I think it's great that you have removed it, it would be great if you also did in your demo.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yep, just pushed the commit a second before your comment. Thanks for enlightening me on QThread::sleep. :-)